# Error with Invoke-Command: 'One or more computer names are not valid'

Tags: powershell

My code throws this error:

> Invoke-Command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects instead of strings.

Each individual part of it seems to work but I am just not getting any visible output.

The array is populated, have tested that. If I remove the variable `$comp` in the `Invoke-Command` and explicitly name a machine there is output, and it's correct. Maybe this due to some clients being offline?

```
$compArray = @()

$compArray = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=xxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xx,DC=xx" `
    | Select-Object Name |Sort-Object Name

ForEach ($comp in $comparray) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp {
        Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*  `
        | Where {($_.InstallSource -like "C:\Users*")} `
            | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallSource `
               | Sort-Object InstallSource |Format-Table –AutoSize}
            }
```

Comment: What if you change Select-Object Name to Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

Comment: You need to use the Name property like this: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp.Name {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your `$compArray` contains a list of computers which you are then selecting their Name property using `Select-Object Name`. This creates an array that looks like this:

```
Name
----
Computer01
Computer02
```

Then within your `foreach` loop you're using `$comp`

```
ForEach ($comp in $comparray) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp
```

Each `$comp` entry is actually an `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer` object (this is what is returned by `Get-ADComputer`) which contains a Name property that you selected.

`Invoke-Command` cannot take an `ADComputer` object as an input for `ComputerName`, which is why you are getting the error. To correct this, you need to refer to just the `Name` property of this object by updating this command with the property name:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp.Name
```

---

The other option is to expand the `Name` property using `Select-Object`:

```
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

This takes the incoming object, enumerates its values and outputs each of those values as a single record, which in your code changes:

```
Name
----
Computer01
Computer02
```

into:

```
Computer01
Computer02
```

Because there is no longer a `Name` property `$comp` will contain the computer name and you do not need to refer to the property of the object like `$comp.Name`.

Comment: James C. That's it! So easy to overlook. Thank you for your help with this.